# Draw Text in ImageView it does not work? Delphi XE8 Android

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe7, delphi-xe8

Draw Text in ImageView it does not work? Delphi XE8 Android

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var
    Rect: TRectF;
  begin
    with ImageViewer1.Bitmap do
      begin
        SetSize(Trunc(ImageViewer1.Width), Trunc(ImageViewer1.Height));
        Clear(TAlphaColors.White);
        Canvas.BeginScene();
        Canvas.Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
        Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColors.Black;
        Canvas.Font.Size := 60;
        Rect.Create(0, 0, Trunc(ImageViewer1.Width), Trunc(ImageViewer1.Height));
        Canvas.FillText(Rect,
                        Edit1.Text,
                        False,
                        100,
                        [],
                        TTextAlign.Center,
                        TTextAlign.Center);
        Canvas.EndScene();
      end;
end;
```

The image is generated small and not draw the text indicated. However Windows image is generated and if you draw the given text. This is very rare because in all platforms should work the same, but in this case it is not. TImage and TImageView tested and none works on Android, it only works in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly due to the  need to create a bitmap that is assigned to the ImageView, before the ImageViewer.Bitmap.Canvas can be utilised.

```
ImageViewer1.Bitmap := TBitmap.Create(Trunc(ImageViewer1.Width), Trunc(ImageViewer1.Height));
```

You may have created this ImageViewer.bitmap elsewhere in the code (before your Button Click event), but your question and code is to vague to know this.  If so the question will need more information.

i.e. the code would be:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var Rect: TRectF;
begin
    ImageViewer1.Bitmap := TBitmap.Create(Trunc(ImageViewer1.Width), Trunc(ImageViewer1.Height));
    with ImageViewer1.Bitmap do
    begin
      ....etc
```